# ExecutorService not sleeping

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have created executor service

```
private ExecutorService webExecutorService;

@Autowired
public void setWebExecutorService() {
    this.webExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
}
```

And executed a runnable which has `Thread.sleep(15000)` But it was not sleeping for the given time

**Runnable code**

```
try {
        int maximum = 999;
        int minimum = 100;
        int randomNumber;
        int port;
        randomNumber = minimum + (int)(Math.random() * ((maximum - minimum) + 1));
        port = randomNumber + 8000;
        while ( !portMap.isEmpty() && portMap.containsValue(String.valueOf(port))) {
            randomNumber = minimum + (int)(Math.random() * ((maximum - minimum) + 1));
            port = randomNumber + 8000;
        }
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*Note: While single thread it's working fine, Where as if we start three threads simultaneously it's not sleeping.*

Comment: Post the code for the runnable.

Comment: @akuzminykh Added the code

Comment: Could you add the code where you add the runnables to the service, or rather invoke them? And how do you check if the threads slept?

Comment: I cannot add that code because of some reasons, I am creating a service using the runnable and kept thread to sleep because the service has to start (running/active) and it will take some time from 9-12 seconds to become active so i want my thread to sleep until the service is up and running.

Comment: In that case, maybe you could do that with a listener, observer or a callback method? Or you could join threads to do a similar thing? Making threads sleep because they have to wait for something to happen is usually bad. It's sadly very hard to help you, when we cannot see the relevant code for your case.

Comment: Will check with callback method, Thanks for your time @akuzminykh